# Defining what columns to fetch at model level of activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is the situation.

A hospital database I don't control, with tables with up to 200 columns... big columns. I know I can use `.select(:col1, :col2)` to thin-down the sql resultset, but in a relation....
`Patient.select(:full_name).find[a,b,c,d.....].include(:visits)`... where Visits has 168 columns and I just need inpatient and outpatient columns, watching a `Select *` on the logs, just hurts, and takes forever to load.

Is there a way to **set in the class**, what columns to include in the model?

Say something like (I'm just making this up)

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  select_columns = [:id, :inpatient_date, :outpatient_date]
  ...
end
```

So that any fetch done to the database uses only those columns on the select statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default scope:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope: -> { select(:id, :inpatient_date, :outpatient_date) }
  ...
end
```

Note that this will only affect queries that return collections of objects, like `where`, etc. All columns will still be available when referencing a single object like `Foo.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pluck` method.

Something like:

```
Patient.includes(:visits).pluck("patients.id, patients.name, visits.inpatient_date, visits.outpatient_date")
```

This will return something like:

> SELECT patients.id, patients.name,  visits.inpatient_date, visits.outpatient_date FROM "patients" LEFT OUTER JOIN "visits" ON "patients"."id" = "visits"."patient_id"

More informations about `pluck` method, can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck

Comment: Tried that... it returns an array. I still need a model.  Thx.